# Firebase Crashlytics setup for flutter on flutter ios

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, crashlytics

Basically, I want to set up Crashlytics for flutter in the ios application but I don't find any proper docs dedicated to ios in the flutterfire docs and I try different tutorials but nothing works. please guide me !!

Comment: Please show what you have tried, where are you stuck, what errors do you get if any etc. I followed [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/crashlytics/overview) and managed to get it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after you define your app in firebase console and download the **"GoogleService-Info.plist"**:

[image]

you must add it to ios folder in flutter app:

[image]

you must add the bellow package to pubspec.yaml file and use it like below link:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_crashlytics: ^2.7.1
```

https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_crashlytics/example

(**This step is optional**) After that, you can add the below script to the build phase for
Crashlytics requires you to upload debug symbols.

You can use a run script build phase for Xcode to automatically upload debug symbols post-build. Find the run script here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?authuser=0

[image]

"${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run"

you must enable crashlytics in firebase console:

[image]

this works(enables) when you crash manually on the button tap (it means that after you launch your app you must make a crash to send a signal to your crashlytics) after that your crashlytics enables.

Comment: Hey i try that but i found that i have to add this script also in `build phases`- `${PODS_ROOT}/FirebaseCrashlytics/run`

Comment: @ArunavaBasu Crashlytics requires you to upload debug symbols.
You can use a run script build phase for Xcode to automatically upload debug symbols post-build. Find the run script. (this step is optional)https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/installation-methods?authuser=0

Comment: @ArunavaBasu the post helps you? or do you have still an issue?